# TIME STAMP off by 5 Hours

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table that stores my users date access, the time stored in this Table is 5 hrs ahead.

i.e. there is a user that access at 4:02 am on my live report

but when i run the query in SQL shows he enter at 9:02 am

How can i compesate for that on my Query?

Comment: How is the data stored?  Are you in a different time zone that your server?

Comment: Data Type = datetime

Comment: same time zone Central

Comment: More detail would be useful.  What query is the report using? Is it doing any formatting on the date?  What query are you using in SQL?

Comment: I have use the following and it seems to fix the issue ,dateadd(HH, -5, a.TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is running on UTC (CDT+5). If you need to adjust to local time, you can use the [`CONVERT_TZ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function.

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html